# How Do I Hide wpf datagrid row selector

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm using the WPF DataGrid control to show some details and a select button, and I don't need the gray selector column down the left-hand side. It's also ruining the beauty of my design.

Is there a way to remove it, or how can I style it to match if not?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Use the `RowHeaderWidth` property:

```
<my:DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" />
```

Note that you can also specify a style or template for it also, should you decide you really do like it and want to keep it because you can do something cool with it.

Comment: for some reason, I couldn't find that anywhere. Feel a bit "doh!" now, but thank you.

Comment: user556009's answer is the correct answer for this. I.e. set HeadersVisibility="Column"

Comment: @scorpion: setting only HeadersVisibility="Column" will cause some column headers to be shifted horizontally compared to cell contents. Setting both HeadersVisibility="Column" and RowHeaderWidth="0" (or just the last one) fixes this problem.

Comment: @JarekKardas It was my case. I played with various HeadersVisibility and RowHeaderWidth values and can't get rid of the shift. Then I leave only HeadersVisibility="Column" and just cleaned and rebuilt the solution and the shift has gone. After that just HeadersVisibility="Column" was enough.

Answer (score 258):

Instead of setting the Width you can completely hide the row headers by setting on the DataGrid

```
HeadersVisibility="Column"
```

Comment: gridView.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column;

Comment: If someone wants to remove all headers: `HeadersVisibility="None"`

Comment: This seems much more correct than setting the width to 0.

Answer (score 6):

**To remove the Row header(Gray field) in Datagrid in WPF**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TrkDataGrid" HeadersVisibility="Column">
</DataGrid>
```

**To remove or hide the Column Header in DataGrid WPF**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TrkDataGrid" HeadersVisibility="Row">
</DataGrid>
```

**To remove or hide both Column and Row Header in DataGrid WPF**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TrkDataGrid" HeadersVisibility="None">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Try this. It is helpful

Comment: That the answer this question deserve

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Looks like the RowHeaderWidth is not supported in XAML BUT you can specify in the code behind right after the bind and it takes out that crappy selector column.

grdName.RowHeaderWidth = 0