# WPF datagrid left column

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I created a datagrid in WPF, there is a thin left column.

I don't know what is it purpose. maybe it is a status column?

How can I disable it?

Comment: See [How Do I Hide wpf datagrid row selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865505/how-do-i-hide-wpf-datagrid-row-selector)

Comment: Thanks for the link, now I know it is a row selector.

Answer (score 5):

The "thin left column" is actually for the row header (more specifically, each row has a [DataGridRowHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridrowheader(v=vs.110).aspx) which, when not filled with anything, causes the datagrid to appear like it has an extra, unnecessary column). Note: changing what appears in the row header is a whole different topic.

[image: An example showing what row headers are]

You can disable it by setting the [HeadersVisibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.headersvisibility(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the DataGrid to "Column" to show only column headers, or "None" in the case where you want no headers at all.

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" />
```

A similar question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865505/how-do-i-hide-wpf-datagrid-row-selector?rq=1).